# Where can I get test samples for Assistant Air Traffic Controller Officer exam?

Tags: air-traffic-control

A few days ago, I applied for the position of Assistant Air Traffic Controller Officer (AATCO), for CAA in Pakistan. The next step is a written test.

What am I supposed to prepare specifically?

My background is in software engineering. Any help/reference will be appreciated.

Comment: I assume the CAA themselves should tell you. Their ATC requirements are [here](http://www.caapakistan.com.pk/upload/PL/LR/specific/pdf/ANO-90.0014-02.pdf) and my best guess is that the written test will be for English proficiency (see section 6.3). But I know literally nothing apart from Google can find and I have no idea about specific questions.

Comment: any portions..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the country you are looking for the certification, rules may be slightly changed. For India following syllabus is applicable (Source: atcguild.com)

At present it is a year-long ab-initio training (Under revision to make it in two sections of six months each)
Modules:

1. Air Traffic Services
2. Aerodromes and Ground Aids
3. Air Legislation
4. Meteorology
5. Communication Procedures
6. Technical
7. Search and Rescue
8. Air Navigation

The selection shall be made on the basis of a

1. Written test
2. 50% questions on subjects relating to educational qualifications
   prescribed
3. 50% on General Knowledge, General Intelligence, General Aptitude,
   English etc. Voice test
4. Personal Interview
5. Medical fitness as per ICAO Annex-1

I Googled for the subject, but didn't find much information on the paper patterns or example papers.